# Partial transparency with C# .NET 3.5 WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawing, transparency

I'm making a .NET 3.5 app with a form that draws a partially transparent black background. I'm overriding OnPaintBackground to accomplish this:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground( PaintEventArgs e )
{
    using ( Brush brush = new SolidBrush( Color.FromArgb( 155, Color.Black ) ) )
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle( brush, e.ClipRectangle );
    } 
}
```

It works, but occasionally the form draws over itself without clearing the screen, making the transparency darker than it should be. I've tried playing with `Graphics.Flush()` and `Graphics.Clear()`, but it either doesn't help or completely removes transparency. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
Here's what it looks like, after starting the app on the left, and after the form redraws itself a few times (in response to tabbing from one control to another) on the right:

[Transparency Issue http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5085/17725729384A10347269148_m.png](http://www.quicksnapper.com/files/5085/17725729384A10347269148_m.png)

**Edit 2:**
I was trying a few things out this morning and noticed that when the desktop behind the transparent portions change, it's not actually being redrawn. For example, if I open Task Manager and put it behind the window, you don't see it refreshing itself. This makes sense with what I've been seeing with the transparency levels. Is there a function to make Windows redraw the area behind your window?

**Edit 3:**
I've tried changing a few properties on the form, but they all result in the form drawing non-transparent black:

```
this.AllowTransparency = true;
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.Opacity = .99;
```

I'm going to try creating a separate window for the transparent portion as overslacked mentioned, but any other ideas are still welcome.

Comment: Is this a situation where you are unable to set the Opacity property?

Comment: Yep, I don't want the form's controls to be transparent, just parts of the window background.

Comment: Is this on Vista with Aero enabled? It would be useful to know so I can try this out myself to try and figure it out.

Comment: It's just Windows XP for now, I haven't begun testing it on Vista yet.

Comment: Marc, the problem with Task Manager "not refreshing itself" is actually your application not repainting. Although you are drawing semitransparently, the actual window is still 100% opaque. That's why Demi suggested the Opacity property. I'll update my answer below with another idea for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would call this expected behavior, actually. What I would do is render my background to an in-memory bitmap and, in the paint event, copy that to the form (basic double-buffering).

If I'm way off base, could you post a screenshot? I don't know that I'm imagining what you're describing correctly.

EDIT:

I'm wondering about your use of OnPaintBackground... pre-.NET, if you were doing double-buffering you'd catch and ignore the WM_ERASKBKGND message (to prevent flicker), render your image to an offscreen buffer, and copy from the buffer to the screen on WM_PAINT. So, try changing from the OnPaintBackground to OnPaint.

I haven't done too much of this kind of thing in .NET, but I had a pretty good handle on it before; I just don't know if it'll translate well or not!

EDIT 2:

Marc, the more I think about what you're trying to do, the more problems appear. I was going to suggest creating a background thread dedicated to capturing the screen and rendering it darkened; however, in order to remove your own form you'd have to set the visibility to false which would create other problems....

If you're unwilling to give up, I would suggest creating two windows and "binding" them together. Create a semi-opaque window (by setting opacity) for your background window, and create a second "normal" window for the foreground. Use SetWindowRgn on the foreground window to cut away the background and position them on top of each other.

Good luck!

Comment: I gave it a try (created a new Bitmap, created a Graphics from the image, filled it the same way as above, and draw it to the screen using the paint event's Graphics) and it had the same issue. It's not a bad idea though, is there any other way of drawing the image to the screen I could try?

Comment: I've updated my answer with something else to try; if you have any code you can send, it's the same username at gmail and I'll see if I can be of any help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the double windows option a try and see if I can't make that work.

Comment: I ended up creating a second transparent background window and now I'm in business. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Is `Graphics.CompositingMode` set to `CompositingMode.SourceCopy`? That should cause painting the background twice to be equivalent to painting it once, since it will replace the existing alpha/color data instead of compositing over it.

Comment: Good suggestion, but when I set it to SourceCopy it kills any transparency and just draws an opaque black background.

Comment: I'm not certain there's any way to get the behavior you desire with pure WinForms. You could use P/Invoke to access the layered window APIs directly and set per-pixel alpha transparency for your window, but I'm not sure it's worth it.

Have you considered using TransparencyKey to make the non-UI parts of your form show through, and then putting a partially opaque window behind it to create the desired effect?