# How to bring up a message popup in C#?

Tags: c#, popup, message

Most recently, while at my mom's house, a phone call came in and the caller ID popped up in a banner on her TV (Comcast). I've seen a similar functionality when the McAfee brings up a virus warning. It was a translucent popup window with the company logo, message and a button or two.

I'd like to mimic this behavior (via C#). This will event driven. My experience in C# is pretty limited, so I'm still feeling out the different libraries. Are there any ideas on where I should start?

Comment: You want to mimic this on your computer, right? Not on your TV? I can only imagine this would be an irritant unless it's accessibility software (like"someone's IMing you" messages for a deaf person).

Answer (score 2):

I recommended to use WPF. Create new window, that will popup and set next properties:

```
WindowStyle="None"
AllowsTransparency="True"
Opacity="0.5" //50% transparent
Topmost="True"
```

`Background` property will set color of window.

Place on window any controls what you need.
Create this window and show when some event happens:

```
YourWindow popup = new YourWindow(/*possible args for message on popup, for example*/);
popup.Show();
```

To place your window in bottom-right corner, as all popups, use next code in windows `Loaded` event:

```
this.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - this.Width;
this.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - this.Height;
```

How to make animation of window movement you can read in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=animate+window+wpf).

Answer (score 0):

If your app is running in the background, you can simply pop up a window and set it to topmost.

Exactly what you do beyond that is going to depend on what type of UI are using (WPF/WinForms.) WPF makes it easier to build a transparent form, as described here:

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2007/06/20/transparent-windows-in-wpf-2/

Transparency in WinForms is a little bit harder, but there are some posts about it:

[Partial transparency with C# .NET 3.5 WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873470/partial-transparency-with-c-net-3-5-winforms)

A couple of things you will want to do with your pop-up window:

1. Disable the minimize/maximize/close buttons
2. Disable the borders

Just put those in your form so it looks better.

-- Dan