# How to do Fade In/Out transition to the background image of a tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, fade

I am currently trying to make a fading transition when changing the background image of a tab during a `ComboBox` `SelectedIndexChanged` event. However, I couldn't find the opacity properties in a tab's background image. Any advice for me how to do this?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        // Some opacity value changing at here
        string pathDesktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        string imagePath1 = pathDesktop + "\\App Background\\";
        tabPage1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath1 + "saadsda.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: Opacity is only supported on top-level windows, not client windows.  That's changing, Windows 8 supports client window opacity, but that's future-music for .NET and probably a lot of your customers.  Fading an image isn't difficult in Winforms, doing so while you are switching tabs ought to be tricky however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fade a panel- Windows forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178559/fade-a-panel-windows-forms)

Answer (score -1):

Like HighCore said in his comment animations are not supported in windows forms applications. But if it is solely the functionality you are looking for then you can set the object to hidden
Object.Visible=false;

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants.