# FadeIn and FadeOut effects for form controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visibility

When I change the `Visible` property of a control or a group of controls on a from, it flickers as they disappear.

I would like to make this appearance or disappearance smooth (Fade In and Fade out).

I thought to use a `Timer` and gradually change the opacity of the controls but they lack the opacity property.

How can I make this effect?

Comment: Might depend on the types of controls you are dealing with; what are they?

Comment: @DonBoitnott toolstripTextBox, toolstripButton and toolstripLabel

Comment: I used another technique by gradually increasing the size of controls to make an smooth transition

Comment: What's your code? Visible is a one-bit value. You could try to change the colors to the background colors but it would be not a simple feat. Or overlay them with another control you fade-in..For this, btw basically outdated kind of glitz in fashion 10-15 years ago; you should indeed consider wpf.

Comment: Fading is pretty easy to do, you do it on a bitmap, not a control.  Code [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10181901/17034).  Doubtful it fixes the real problem, whatever it might be.